# How to add multiple Bindable services to a grpc server builder?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I have the gRPC server code as below:

```
public void buildServer() { 
  List<BindableService> theServiceList = new ArrayList<BindableService>(); 
  theServiceList.add(new CreateModuleContentService()); 
  theServiceList.add(new RemoveModuleContentService()); 

  ServerBuilder<?> sb = ServerBuilder.forPort(m_port); 
  for (BindableService aService : theServiceList) { 
    sb.addService(aService); 
  } 
  m_server = sb.build(); 
}
```

and client code as below:

```
public class JavaMainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CreateModuleService createModuleService = new CreateModuleService();
        ESDStandardResponse esdReponse = createModuleService.createAtomicBlock("8601934885970354030", "atm1");

        RemoveModuleService moduleService = new RemoveModuleService();
        moduleService.removeAtomicBlock("8601934885970354030", esdReponse.getId());
    }
}
```

While I am running the client I am getting an exception as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method grpc.blocks.operations.ModuleContentServices/createAtomicBlock is unimplemented
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:233)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:214)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:139)
```

In the above server class, if I am commenting the line  `theServiceList.add(new RemoveModuleContentService());` then the `CreateModuleContentService` service is working fine, also without commenting all the services of `RemoveModuleContentService` class are working as expected, which means the problem is with the first service when another gets added.

Can someone please suggest how can I add two services to Server Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A particular gRPC service can only be implemented once per server. Since the name of the gRPC service in the error message is `ModuleContentServices`, I'm assuming `CreateModuleContentService` and `RemoveModuleContentService` both extend `ModuleContentServicesImplBase`.

When you add the same service multiple times, the last one wins. The way the generated code works, every method of a service is registered even if you don't implement that particular method. Every service method defaults to a handler that simply returns "UNIMPLEMENTED: Method X is unimplemented". `createAtomicBlock` isn't implemented in `RemoveModuleContentService`, so it returns that error.

If you interact with the `ServerServiceDefinition` returned by `bindService()`, you can mix-and-match methods a bit more, but this is a more advanced API and is intended more for frameworks to use because it can become verbose to compose every application service individually.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you correctly identified the problem. I was adding the same service multiple times.